# simplexml_load_file just stopped working

Tags: php, simplexml

I read a blog into my website using somehting like this...

```
define('BLOG_PATH', 'http://kvfcblog.blogspot.co.uk/feeds/posts/default'); 
$url = BLOG_PATH . "?alt=rss&category=" . $page;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

where $page = index, so reading from

```
http://kvfcblog.blogspot.co.uk/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&category=index
```

this works fine on my localhost, and used to work just as well on my live site, until today, when I started getting these errors ...

```
simplexml_load_file(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/shdpbmib/public_html/rss/kvfc_rss.php on line 17
simplexml_load_file(http://kvfcblog.blogspot.co.uk/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&amp;category=index): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/shdpbmib/public_html/rss/kvfc_rss.php on line 17
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http://kvfcblog.blogspot.co.uk/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&amp;category=index&quot; in /home/shdpbmib/public_html/rss/kvfc_rss.php on line 17
```

Strangley, it still works fine from my localhost

Any ideas? I tried rawurlencode(), but that didn't make any difference

Comment: What is your `ALLOW_FOPEN` configuration in `php.ini` ?

Comment: You probably got banned for flooding

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find out what ALLOW_FOPEN is set to

Comment: how can I find out for sure if my website has been banned for flooding? It's my Google Blogger blog, so is there a way I can un-ban it if that's the case?

Comment: ok, allow_url_fopen is set to On

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is getting pretty old but... can you ping the address you're trying to reach? Or can you reach it any other way?

```
ping your_server_ip
ping stackoverflow.com
```

If pinging fails, that means something's wrong with your server. It looks like the hostname you're passing to run can't be resolved. You can try:

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8080)
```